# Como cascatear relacionamento?

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho uma classe mapeada com hibernate, porém, ao salvar um objeto é cascateado todo o objeto para a tabela filho (o que é esperado). O problema é que são salvos objetos iguais ao invés de apenas relacionar o objeto filho ao objeto pai.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Atributo> atributos;
```

Acreditei que colocar `equals` iria ser suficiente para a API, mas não funcionou como esperado.

Alguém sabe como fazer de tal forma que não precise verificar se o objeto existe no banco toda vez que a função for chamada?

No exemplo que fiz ficou assim:

```
@Entity
public class TestePai implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long ID;
    String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    TesteFilho testefilho;
}

@Entity
public class TesteFilho implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long ID;

    String name;
}
```

Usei uma tarefa para executar.

```
@Component
public class TesteScheduller {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAdminConfig.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Autowired
    TestePaiRepository testePaiRepository;

    @Autowired
    TesteFilhoRepository testeFilhoRepository;

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 2000L, fixedRate = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L)
    public void teste() {
        log.trace("\n\n********************************************************************\n\n");
        log.trace("Start TesteScheduller in: {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        TestePai pai = new TestePai();
        TesteFilho filho = new TesteFilho();
        if (this.testeFilhoRepository.findOneByName(filho.getName()) != null) {
            filho = this.testeFilhoRepository.findOneByName(filho.getName());
        }
        pai.setTestefilho(filho);
        log.trace("Pai 1:\n" + pai);
        testePaiRepository.saveAndFlush(pai);
        log.trace("\n\n********************************************************************\n\n");
        pai = new TestePai();
        pai.setName("Bom dia");
        filho = new TesteFilho();
        if (this.testeFilhoRepository.findOneByName(filho.getName()) != null) {
            filho = this.testeFilhoRepository.findOneByName(filho.getName());
        }
        pai.setTestefilho(filho);
        log.trace("Pai 1:\n" + pai);
        testePaiRepository.save(pai);
        testePaiRepository.saveAndFlush(pai);
    }
}
```

Isso me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.andersoney.teste.model.Teste.TesteFilho; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.andersoney.teste.model.Teste.TesteFilho
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:299)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
    at com.andersoney.teste.scheduller.TesteScheduller.teste(TesteScheduller.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

O principal desafio na situação real que irei aplicar o que for descoberto aqui: o objeto terá muitos filhos, uma lista `ManytoMany`, e nesta lista haverá tanto objetos que existem, como outros objetos que não no banco. Posso fazer a checagem como está acima e adicionar o objeto já com a `ID` definida do banco. Mas precisa ser persistida a chave estrangeira dos que tiver `ID`, e dos que não tiver, deve ser salva e obtida a chave estrangeira como o Hibernate já faz.

Comment: Os atributos dos objetos filhos/pai são alterados, ou zerados, caso são `new`? Pois essa é a única forma deles serem inseridos novamente, na minha opinião.

Comment: Gustavo, O que espero é o comportamento contrario a isto. Quero que os dados sejam verificados se existe no banco e depois salve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `<T> T merge(T entity)` ao invés do `void persist(java.lang.Object entity)`. Ele é utilizado para vincular entidades que estão no estado *detached* (entidades que o podem, ou não, existir no banco de dados e não são "conhecidas" pelo `EntityManager` ) ao `EntityManager`.

É importante ressaltar que essa busca ao banco de dados só será realizada se um `@Id` for informado.

Exemplo:

**Classe Pai:**

```
@Entity
public class Pai {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { 
        CascadeType.PERSIST, 
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    private List<Filho> filho = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters e setters omitidos

    public final void addFilho(Filho filho) {
        this.filho.add(filho);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Pai)) return false;
        Pai other = (Pai) o;
        return getId() == other.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Pai [id=").append(id).append(", nome=").append(nome).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Classe Filho:**

```
@Entity
public class Filho {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    //getters e setters omitidos

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Filho)) return false;
        Filho other = (Filho) o;
        return getId() == other.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Filho [id=").append(id).append(", nome=").append(nome).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Teste:**

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();

Filho f1 = new Filho(); //Entidade no estado new
f1.setNome("Filho 1");

Filho f2 = new Filho(); //Entidade no estado new
f2.setNome("Filho 2");

Pai p1 = new Pai();     //Entidade no estado new
p1.setNome("Pai 1");
p1.addFilho(f1);
p1.addFilho(f2);

//Persiste tanto pai quanto filhos
em.persist(p1);
em.getTransaction().commit();

em.clear();         //Remove todas as entidades do em deixando-as "detached"

em.getTransaction().begin();

Filho f3 = new Filho(); //Entidade no estado new
f3.setNome("Filho 3");

//Entidade no estado detached
//É a mesma entidade que o Filho 1, porém representado por outro
//objeto que o EntityManager ainda não conhece
Filho f4 = new Filho(); 
f4.setId(f1.getId());
f4.setNome("Filho 1");

Pai p2 = new Pai();
p2.setNome("Pai 2");
p2.addFilho(f2);    //Aqui ele dará um SELECT no BD durante o flush
p2.addFilho(f3);    //Add filho no estado new
p2.addFilho(f4);    //Aqui ele dará outro SELECT no BD durante o flush

em.merge(p2);

em.getTransaction().commit();

em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Lifecycle$Pai p ", Pai.class)
    .getResultList()
    .forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("\n\n");

//Pode ver que não haverá filhos duplicados
em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Lifecycle$Filho f ", Filho.class)
    .getResultList()
    .forEach(System.out::println);


em.close();
emf.close();
```

Comment: Felipe não estou usando entity manager factory, logo por mais boa vontade que tenha o que me passou não funciona. Preciso de algo usando o JPA que usa JPARepository.

Comment: @AndersoneyRodrigues O  `JpaRepository` usa um `EntityManager`. Você pode pegá-lo através de uma implementação customizada do `JpaRepository`. Dê uma olhada [nesse](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) e [nesse](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/) link para saber como.